# Stata: using foreach to rename numeric variables

Tags: foreach, stata

I have a large dataset where subsets of variables have been entered with the same prefix, followed by an underscore and some details. They are all binary YN and the variables are all doubles. For example, I have the variables `onsite_healthclinic` and `onsite_CBO` where values can only be 1 or 0.

I want to `rename` them all according to the question they are on the survey I'm working off of (so the above variables would become `q0052_healthclinic` and `q0052_CBO`), but if I use the code below using `substr` I (obviously) get `type mismatch`:

```
foreach var in onsite_healthclinic onsite_CBO {
        local new = substr(`var', 8, .)
        rename `new' q0052_`new'
    }
```

My question is, is there another command other than `substr` that I can use so that I don't have to either a) convert all of the variables to strings first; or b) rename them all manually (there are ~20 in each subset, so while doable, it's a waste of time).

Comment: `substr()` is a function, not a command.

Comment: Use `compress` to reduce memory use by data. There is no reason to store binary variables as `double`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no need for a loop here at all. Although the essential answer is one line long I give here a complete, self-contained answer.

```
clear 
set obs 1 
foreach v in onsite_healthclinic onsite_CBO { 
    gen `v' = 1 
}

rename onsite_*  q0052_* 

describe, fullnames
```

This answer implies that you've not studied the help under `rename groups`.

Answer (score 1):

Will this work?

```
foreach var in onsite_healthclinic onsite_CBO {
    local new = substr("`var'", 8, .)
    rename onsite_`new' q0052_`new'
}
```

I added quotes around the call to the local `var` in the `substr` function and added `onsite_` to the rename and that seemed to work.

Comment: Nick's answer is in fact the better one, I would accept his instead